# Using Case Statement in linked servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
Select distinct 
    Case 
        When ABC = 'C1' then 'C1'
        When ABC = 'C1C' then 'C1C' 
        When ABC = 'C2' then 'C2' 
        When ABC = 'C3' then 'C3'
        When ABC = 'C3C' then 'C3C' 
        When ABC = 'C3CC' then  'C3CC'
        When ABC = 'C4' then 'C4' 
        When ABC = 'C4C' then  'C4C'
        When ABC = 'C4CC' then 'C4CC' 
        When ABC = 'C6' then  'C6'
        When ABC = 'C7' then  'C7'
        When ABC = 'C8' then  'C8'
        When ABC = 'F' then  'F'
        When ABC = 'F2' then 'F2'
        When ABC = 'V' then 'V'
        When ABC = 'V2' then 'V2'
    End as ABC
from LinkedServer.database.dbo.Tblname
```

When i execute above sql on regular database works perfect with no errors but 
if i use linked server prefix then i get below error.

> Error message: Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Statement(s) could
>   not be prepared. Msg 125, Level 15, State 4, Line 1 Case expressions
>   may only be nested to level 10.

It works fine if I delete some case statements(usually less than 10 cases) works fine.
Any thoughts or work around:
One work around I know: Create SP/View/Function on Linked Server with however many case statement and then call that created SP/View/Function. I'm not looking for this though.

Answer (score 1):

Your case can also be written

```
Case When ABC IN ('C1','C1C','C2'...) then ABC End as ABC
```

If you're using a CASE statement with a mountain of built-in translations to descriptions, then you're doing it wrong. You should be creating a lookup table instead and performing a LEFT JOIN.  The lookup table can exist on either side of the linked server.

```
select
    l.description as abc
    ...
from LinkedServer.database.dbo.Tblname t
left join ABCValues l on t.ABC = l.value
```

Comment: Using IN operator is good but my sql code was just rough sketch depending upon each values we need make out something else for instance Case When ABC = 'C1' then 'Check the Information' Case When ABC = 'C2' then 'Check Front desk Information' and so on.. so i can't use ABC IN ('C1', 'C2') ...

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, you cannot have more than 10 `when` in such a `case` statement.

In your case, it is easy to fix with an `in` clause:

```
case when ABC in ('C1', . . . ) then ABC
end
```

If your SQL code is more complex, then you might be able to use a mapping table and join:

```
with mapping as (
    select 'C1' as val, 'C1' as newval union all
    . . .
)
select m.newval, . . .
from LinkedServer.database.dbo.Tblname t left outer join
     mapping m
     on t.ABC = m.val
```

Comment: Using IN operator is good but my sql code was just rough sketch depending upon each values we need make out something else for instance Case When ABC = 'C1' then 'Check the Information' Case When ABC = 'C2' then 'Check Front desk Information' and so on.. so i can't use ABC IN ('C1', 'C2') ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of LINKEDSERVER.DB.dbo.Table, you can use OPENQUERY and have not encounter this CASE limitation

Answer (score 0):

As Steven mentionned, use OPENQUERY whenever possible.

```
SELECT ABC 
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,
'Select distinct 
    Case 
        When ABC = ''C1'' then ''C1 or whatever''
        When ABC = ''C1C'' then ''C1C blabla '' 
        When ABC = ''C2'' then ''C2'' 
        When ABC = ''C3'' then ''C3''
        When ABC = ''C3C'' then ''C3C'' 
        When ABC = ''C3CC'' then  ''C3CC''
        When ABC = ''C4'' then ''C4'' 
        When ABC = ''C4C'' then  ''C4C''
        When ABC = ''C4CC'' then ''C4CC'' 
        When ABC = ''C6'' then  ''C6''
        When ABC = ''C7'' then  ''C7''
        When ABC = ''C8'' then  ''C8''
        When ABC = ''F'' then  ''F''
        When ABC = ''F2'' then ''F2''
        When ABC = ''V'' then ''V''
        When ABC = ''V2'' then ''V2''
    End as ABC
from database.dbo.Tblname')
```